# Is there any methods to set default node attributes for subgraph using c++ libgraph?

Tags: c++, graphviz

I want to set the default node attributes for subgraph. The agnodeattr function can only take effects on the root graph, but not subgraph. 
I know the easy way to set the default attributes one by one duplicatedly for all nodes in the subgraph. For example, a subgraph has 5 nodes.

```
agsafeset(node_1, "label", "Class1", "");
agsafeset(node_1, "shape", "ellipse", "");
agsafeset(node_1, "color", "darkgreen", "");
agsafeset(node_1, "width", "2.5", "");
agsafeset(node_1, "height", "1.2", "");

agsafeset(node_2, "label", "Class2", "");
agsafeset(node_2, "shape", "ellipse", "");
agsafeset(node_2, "color", "darkgreen", "");
agsafeset(node_2, "width", "2.5", "");
agsafeset(node_2, "height", "1.2", "");

agsafeset(node_3, "label", "Class3", "");
agsafeset(node_3, "shape", "ellipse", "");
agsafeset(node_3, "color", "darkgreen", "");
agsafeset(node_3, "width", "2.5", "");
agsafeset(node_3, "height", "1.2", "");

agsafeset(node_4, "label", "Class4", "");
agsafeset(node_4, "shape", "ellipse", "");
agsafeset(node_4, "color", "darkgreen", "");
agsafeset(node_4, "width", "2.5", "");
agsafeset(node_4, "height", "1.2", "");

agsafeset(node_5, "label", "Class5", "");
agsafeset(node_5, "shape", "ellipse", "");
agsafeset(node_5, "color", "darkgreen", "");
agsafeset(node_5, "width", "2.5", "");
agsafeset(node_5, "height", "1.2", "");
```

But this method is not convenient for large graph creation. 
Please give some hint, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a `for` loop.

You'd then easily be able to increase the number of dummy data from 5 to 5000.

Comment: So there are no methods to set the default node attributes directly for the subgraph?